# Using * to create ntuples (unexpected behavior)

Tags: python

Can somebody explain why this creates a list of 5 elements:

```
['']*5
```

While this create a tuple of 1 element

```
('')*5
```

But this creates a tuple with six elements:

```
('', '')*3
```

Question: is there a way to create tuple with an odd number of elements without using a generator (i.e. by using *)?

Comment: `('')` isn't tuple. `('',)` is a tuple.

Answer (score 4):

`('')` is actually not a tuple, it is a string. You want to write `('',)`.

Comment: (facepalm), thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Pretty common error. I've made it more than once. :-)